# How to stop a Countdowntimer in a service from an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, countdowntimer

I have a `Countdown timer` in a service that will trigger a series of events if not stopped. 
I start an `Activity` with a text field showing countdown remaining, and if this dialog is not dismissed/closed then the timer will execute its `onFinish()` instructions.

I can update the `Activity` using broadcasts in the `onTick()` method of the countdown timer.

The question for me is how do I send a message back to the service to `cancel()` the timer if the user clears the warning/alert dialog.

Side question: The `onTick()` method *Callback fired on regular interval* what do they consider a *regular interval* I don't want to be sending an update broadcast to the activity every ms. Won't that be excessive broadcasts then? When I only have to update the countdown every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, and it depends on how often you do it, but you could use a shared preference - writing it in your app and checking it in the service.
Regarding the side question - you are setting the interval when instantiating your timer, as this is the constructor  `CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)`

Comment: Don't know if it is the best solution either, but it does work, and I am now currently using it. Another alternative would be to call the service via startService() and in `onStartCommand()` use an `Intent` that specifies an update. As the service should still be _running_ if not you could handle the fact that the service was closed.

Comment: I may have to ask another question, as I cannot figure out what happens if `onStartCommand()` is still processing. And then another call to `startService()` comes in. Does it queue? Or will multiple `onStartCommand()` calls run in parallel?

Comment: I do not know what will happen - but I believe you will find your answer here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html, under 'Service Lifecycle'. If you still have doubts, this seems like something that proper logging and time stamp comparison can resolve.